# what is the diff between creating object and object()

Tags: c++

```
class A{
   public:
      A(){cout<<"Constructor called"<<endl;}

      ~A(){cout<<"Destructor called"<<endl;} 
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    A x;
    A y();
    return 0;
}
```

what is the difference between x and y as x prints while y doesn't print'

Comment: `A y();` -- So how do you declare a function called `y` that takes no parameters and returns an `A` object?  See the ambiguity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> A x;
> ```

This is declaration of a variable.

> ```
> A y();
> ```

This is declaration of a function.